# Turn-based battle system action depending on action delay value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I built an active turn-based battle system in Unity and while I can now cycle through every player/enemy and choose their action, one of my design choice is to have a certain delay in seconds for every action to happen. This means that even if playerA make a choice before playerB, if playerB's choice has a shorter delay, then it should be processed first.

Right now, if playerA choose a spell that should take 10 seconds to cast but playerB choose to do a physical attack, which has a delay of 2 seconds, he has to wait until playerA cast his spell before his turn come...

The way the ATB works is that I have a list of Actors, which is a class containing all of the information on the type of action taken, who is taking it and it's target.

I have this code:

```
public class BattleStateMachine : MonoBehaviour {

    public enum BattleStates {
        INITIALIZE,
        WAITING,
        PROCESS_ACTION,
        IDLE,
        CHECK_IF_ALIVE,
        WON,
        LOST
    }

    public BattleStates currState;

    public List<Actor> actors = new List<Actor>();      //List of actors, which contains the details of the action taken by the battler

    public List<GameObject> heroesToManage = new List<GameObject>();

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {

        switch(currState) {

            case BattleStates.INITIALIZE: {
                    currState = BattleStates.WAITING;
                    break;
                }

            case BattleStates.WAITING: {
                    if(actors.Count > 0)
                        currState = BattleStates.PROCESS_ACTION;
                    break;
                }

            case BattleStates.PROCESS_ACTION: {
                    HeroStateMachine hsm = actors[0].Origin.GetComponent<HeroStateMachine>();
                    hsm.target = actors[0].Target;
                    hsm.currState = HeroStateMachine.TurnStates.ACTION;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}

public class Actor
{
    public GameObject Origin;
    public GameObject Target;

    public BaseAction ChosenAction;
}

public class HeroStateMachine : MonoBehaviour {

    public BattleStateMachine bsm;

    public enum TurnStates {
        WAITING,
        ADDTOLIST,
        IDLE,
        ACTION,
        DEAD
    }

    public TurnStates currState;

    void Update () {

        switch(currState) {

            case TurnStates.WAITING: {
                    UpdateATBGauge();
                    break;
                }

            case TurnStates.ADDTOLIST: {
                    bsm.heroesToManage.Add(this.gameObject);
                    currState = TurnStates.IDLE;

                    break;
                }

            case TurnStates.IDLE: {
                    break;
                }

            case TurnStates.ACTION: {
                    StartCoroutine(TimeForAction());
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator TimeForAction() {

        if(actionStarted)
            yield break;

        actionStarted = true;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(bsm.actors[0].ChosenAction.ActionDelay);

        DoDamage();

        bsm.actors.RemoveAt(0);
        bsm.currState = BattleStateMachine.BattleStates.WAITING;
        actionStarted = false;

        statsPanel.progressGauge.value = 0f;
        currState = TurnStates.WAITING;
    }
}
```

To explain the way it works, I'll try an example.

The HeroStateMachine's ATB gauge is filled, it gets added to the BattleStateMachine heroesToManage list. Then we choose to cast a fireball spell on EnemyA. An instance of the Actor class gets created with the hero as the origin, EnemyA as the target and the spell "Fireball" as the chosenAttack. the instance gets added to the actors list. Assuming it's the first instance of Actor in the actors list, we start the Coroutine and so we wait 3.5 seconds (the delay on the Fireball spell. Once the time has passed, we deal damage to EnemyA, remove the first instance of Actor in the list and the ATB Gauge will reset.

Now, to fix the problem and process the fastest action in the actors list first, I thought about constantly monitoring the actors list and reordering it so that the closest to completion always end up first. However, I fear that this will be REALLY costly on CPU power, plus, I would need to keep a timer going for every single actors, probably eating even more CPU cycles...

Is there another way to do what I want, or would constantly reordering the list every time a new Actor gets added to it really be the only way to do this?

Comment: Why not allow players to launch attacks when their gauges are full, letting them determine that individually rather than relying on an FSM to try to juggle all this? You can still use the state machine to set the overall state of the battle (eg. Starting/Battling/Won/Lost), but don't use it to govern the actions of the individual actors at such a low level.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit, maybe give an example? I'm not sure I understand what you mean here. Sure it would be way easier to have each HSM take it's action without relying on the BSM but how can I keep it ordered? Say I have two heroes getting their turn really close to each other, I can't choose the action of both at the same time, meaning that I need to have some way to know who's the next one to act. Also, once this choice is made, if another hero chooses a quicker action, I have to keep track of the turn order, no?

Comment: Are you planning on displaying the turn order, that requires you to actually calculate this? Otherwise, have the hero raise an event with the battle manager when they're ready to take their action (so you can switch from a polling to event-based way of structuring this part of the system). Then your battle manager can do whatever you like with that information (eg. Pausing gauge filling while the skill activates, displaying the name of the skill, etc.)